# CommitFailedException doesn't throw

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Actually I have some code that fails with this exception

First excepction of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException' at EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

This exception avoid to save the changes at my DB, but doesn't throw any exeption in my code. It Just apears at Results (output) window when I'm debuging.

Some things I tryed...

```
Try
{
   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //  It never stosp Here
   var somethingshere = ex.message;  
}
```

But doesn't stop and doesn't throw any other error.

How can I do to catch it and see the exception details ?

**NOTE:** I'm usign EF 6.1 and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Did you check the Break when an exception is thrown option in debug --> exception  menu ?

Comment: Yes I did, It trhow me another EF Exceptions.

Comment: @DeJaVo You are ok about it, allready it trhow it. very very tks for your help.

Comment: @DeJaVo Exception problem was solved but the problem is like about EF first excpetion of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.CommitFailedException' en EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server. See the inner exception and http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=313468 for more information. Doesn't help that link talk obout conection problems but this exception is always present with my code. MY HEAD IS ABOUT TO EXPLOTE. any way very tks .

Comment: read my answer. I posted a link that might help you to implement your own exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:  check the 'Break when an exception is thrown' option in debug --> exception menu.

[image: Debug menu]

If that fail - 
I think this might be helpful:

> If your application can handle these being thrown on a relatively infrequent basis (e.g. the user can just verify retry the last operation themselves if needed) you can avoid the overhead of CommitFailureHandler by adding an implementation of TransactionHandler that just throws a helpful exception.

Source: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Handling%20of%20Transaction%20Commit%20Failures%20

The source itself is very informative.
I hope it will help you sort things out.